# Why does the [0] beside 'cows' add the 'cows' array to the animals array as an array item and not as an array within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does the [0] beside 'cows' add the 'cows' array to the animals array as an array item. With no [0] beside 'cows', it's added to the animals array as an array within an array.

```
const animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

const count = animals.push(['cows'][0]);
console.log(count);
// expected output: 4
console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows"]

animals.push(['lion']);
console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows", ['lion']]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you push ['cows'][0] you're pushing the element with index 0 of the ['cows'] array, so you're pushing 'cows'.

If you just push ['cows'] you're pushing the entire one-element array to the array.

Not sure if that is what you are asking but I tried to explain the best way I could.

Comment: You can mark this as correct if it helped.  Just to add 
const cowItem = 'cows';
const cowsArray = [cowItem];
and cowItem === cowsArray[0];